# Select last value in each group

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In database I have two table. I want to join two tables and get last row each `SensorType`

***Sensors table:***

| Id | CodeNumber | PortNumber | SensorType | IsActive |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13 | Dht11 | 3 | 0 | 1 |
| 14 | Dht11 | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 17 | Global | 100 | 4 | 1 |
| 18 | Dht11 | 3 | 1 | 1 |
| 19 | Dht11 | 3 | 3 | 1 |

***SensorsValue table (`SensorId` is foreign key Sensors table):***

| Id | SensorId | Value | DateOfRetrevingValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 19 | 13 | 25 | 2021-07-23 08:50:27.0000000 |
| 20 | 14 | 45 | 2021-07-23 09:50:27.0000000 |
| 21 | 17 | 12 | 2021-07-23 10:50:27.0000000 |
| 22 | 18 | 24 | 2021-07-23 11:50:27.0000000 |
| 23 | 19 | 45 | 2021-07-23 12:50:27.0000000 |
| 24 | 13 | 23 | 2021-07-23 13:50:27.0000000 |
| 25 | 14 | 56 | 2021-07-23 14:50:27.0000000 |
| 26 | 17 | 23 | 2021-07-23 15:50:27.0000000 |
| 27 | 18 | 34 | 2021-07-23 16:50:27.0000000 |
| 28 | 19 | 23 | 2021-07-23 17:50:27.0000000 |

I want to join two tables and select `SensorType` from `Sensors` table and last `Value` (from `SensorsValue`) each `SensorType`. In this case i want get result:

```
|SensorType|Value|
|----------|-----|
|    0     | 23  |
|    2     | 56  |
|    4     | 23  |
|    1     | 34  |
|    3     | 13  |
```

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group-mysql) and use this statement:

```
SELECT distinct Sensor.Type, MAX(SensorValues.Id), SensorValues.Value
FROM Sensor
INNER JOIN SensorValues ON Sensor.Id=SensorValues.SensorId
GROUP BY Sensor.Type
```

but I got error:

> Column 'SensorValues.Value' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

If I use this statement without `SensorValues.Value` query work, but I got result:

```
|SensorType|Id|
|----------|--|
```

Comment: Select either MySQL or SQL Server, not both. Specify precise version also. Provide complete error message, not a part of it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should use `first_value`

```sql
select distinct t1.SensorType,
       first_value(t2.value) over(partition by t1.SensorType order by t2.DateOfRetrevingValue desc)
  from Sensors t1,
       SensorsValue t2
 where t1.id = t2.SensorId
```

Comment: Nice solution, but wouldn't be cleaner to just use `last_value` instead of `first_value`, so you won't need to order descendingly ?.

Comment: This is just my personal habit, first_value can replace last_value, using only one of them can make me more proficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
SELECT Sensor.Type,  SensorValues.Value
FROM Sensor
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT MAX(ID)Id, SensorId FROM SensorValues GROUP BY SensorId
)mId  ON Sensor.Id=mId.SensorId
INNER JOIN SensorValues ON mId.Id=SensorValues.Id
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a very handy place to use `apply`:

```
select s.*, sv.value, sv.DateOfRetrevingValue
from sensors s cross apply
     (select top (1) sv.*
      from SensorValues sv 
      where s.Id = sv.SensorId
      order by sv.DateOfRetrevingValue desc
     ) sv;
```

One advantage of this approach is that you can returns as many columns as you like.  I also suspect that that performance will be better than a `select distinct` approach.